# How to send "this" to named function in event binding statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am bit stuck, don't know if its possible to turn:

```
$("#id").click(function(){  
    var that = jQuery(this);  
    wildFunction(that);
});
```

into

```
$("#id").click(wildFunction(this));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"this" is a scope variable so it would be present in the event handler no matter how you bind it. so this would work:

```
$("#id").click(wildFunction);

function wildFunction()
{
    var that = $(this); // this is valid here, and we can make jQuery object with it
}
```

Comment: I edited your answer just a bit, do you agree with edit?
it now answers exactly what i asked, it might be easier for someone to read it "this" :P way

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that — or rather, you could, but it wouldn't be useful. You need to have that function syntax there. In your second code sample, `this` would be whatever it is in the code *calling* `click`, where I'm assuming from your first code sample you want it to be the `this` that jQuery sets up for the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but you can use

```
$("#id").click( wildFunction );
```

and inside the `wildFunction` method `this` will refer to the `#id` DOM element.